# Testing a 3d object/map rendered by a web application

Tags: testing, automation, 3d

Suppose there exist a 3d model say, created from a desktop application like autocad or rhino3d. This model is editable and savable by desktop application

assume, the snapshots of this 3d model are rendered from a web application on to a browser, in this case, how can the rendered model be verified against the original 3d model.

Answer (score 1):

Few ways to do that:

- Make screenshots of web\desktop models and compare them.
- Convert web model back to desktop and compare then.

Comment: thank you, the hints are useful, probably involves computer vision skills to get accuracy